# Twitter-like tweet box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

so what I'm hoping to do is having a box that's similar to the tweet box. When the user enters '@' (I know, use `keyup` to detect when), and then he types a letter (i.e. 'J'), I want to get 4 of the people he's following and show it as a suggestion (i.e. James, Jay, Jack, etc...). The way I would approach this is make an AJAX call which will query the sql table to find all of the users whom the user follows and whose names begin with that substring, but what I've noticed that FB does with friends is that it loads all of the user's friends upon visit, meaning that if you were to type '@' then it would scour a client-side array rather than constantly query the database. Although I'm not so sure if that's better... Is it better? Also, when would I load all of the user's following users? As soon as he/she visits any page? And is it conventional?

tl;dr - Should users that a logged-in user be pre-loaded and stored as an array or constantly obtained by querying the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any jquery framework like angular.js ?

Comment: @dksaini14 No, I'm not.

Comment: When a ajax call has been sent to server a thread is generated in Server's CPU. So if you have 10 user on line search for a friend iist it will consume ore CPU. so better option is that fetch list in group. e.g. if you want to search Arjun, and type A, it will fetch list of all friend with name A. so when you type R(second letter) it will not send ajax request.

Comment: @dksaini14 Ohh, I see. Post an answer so I can mark you as best answer.

Comment: @dksaini14: Angular.js is not a "jQuery framework", whatever that is.

Comment: I have asked are you using jquery or any other framework like angular.js

Comment: @dksaini14 'cept jQuery is not a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an ajax call has been sent to server a thread is generated in Server's CPU. So if you have 10 user on line search for a friend list it will consume more CPU. 
So better option is that fetch list in group. e.g. you want to search Arjun,
If you type A, it will fetch list of all friend with name A. so when you type R(second letter) it will not send ajax request again.